# Replacing a dimmer switch to a normal switch

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch

I have 4 switches on my switch board. One regular switch and three dimmer switches. I need to swap one of the dimmer switch with the regular switch

I have a dimmer switch which has three wires. one green (connected to copper wire) and two black wires. The regular switch has one red, one black and a copper wire. It would have been easy if it was a like to like wire setup but I have no idea how to replace it. Please help me.

Pictures can be found here : [Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jic5j.jpg) (first image is the dimmer switch, second picture is the regular switch. I need to swap them. If it's difficult to swap It's okay if I just convert the dimmer to a regular switch)

Comment: Can you post the pictures?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel : Yes, Pls find the updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Red's just another hot(-ish)

For the switch going to where the dimmer was:

- Green wire to green screw
- Each of the free black wires to a brass screw (the switch doesn't care)

For the dimmer going to where the switch was:

- Bare wire to the green screw (the screw that was hooked to the green wire)
- Black wire to one of the brass screws
- Red wire to the other brass screw

If the dimmer doesn't like it, switch the black and red wires around -- this shouldn't be an issue for a regular dimmer though.

Comment: Thanks. So the switch will not have any red attached to it. It will just have the two black wires on each of the brass screws and a green one on the other side? Am I correct?

Comment: @Damien-Amen -- that sounds right, yes